# How to avoid MQTT reconnect Loop

Tags: web-server, mqtt

I have the following code designed to allow me to control my device from my website using **mqtt broker** while internet is available. I also built in a **local webserver** to control the device in case of internet outage given I'm still connected to the same router my device is connected to.

```js
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

int ledPin = 2; 

const char* ssid = "SSID";
const char* password = "PASS";
const char* mqtt_server = "MQTTSERVER";
const char* mqtt_user = "MQTTUSER";
const char* mqtt_pass = "MQTTPASS";
const char* mqtt_topic = "topic";
String mqttpayload;

WiFiServer server(80);
WiFiClient espClient; 
PubSubClient client(espClient);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { delay(100); Serial.print(".");  }  Serial.println("");
  
  Serial.print("Connected to WiFi");  
  
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);    server.begin();  
}

void loop() {
  client.setCallback(callback);
  reconnect();
  if ( mqttpayload == "OFF" ) {   digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); Serial.println("Switced OFF"); }
  if ( mqttpayload == "ON" ) {   digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);  Serial.println("Switced ON"); }
  mqttpayload = "";


  WiFiClient cclient = server.available();
  if (!cclient) {  return;  }  while(!cclient.available()){  }
  String request = cclient.readStringUntil('\r');  Serial.println(request);  cclient.flush();

  int value = HIGH;
  if (request.indexOf("/LED=ON") != -1)   { 
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);    value = LOW;      Serial.println("Publish message: ON");    reconnect();  client.publish(mqtt_topic, "ON", true); 
  } 
  if (request.indexOf("/LED=OFF") != -1)  { 
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);   value = HIGH;     Serial.println("Publish message: OFF");    reconnect(); client.publish(mqtt_topic, "OFF", true); 
  }

  cclient.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");  
  cclient.println("Content-Type: text/html");  
  cclient.println(""); 
  cclient.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");  
  cclient.println("<html>");  
  cclient.print("LED status: "); 
  
  if(value == HIGH) {    cclient.print("OFF");  } else {    cclient.print("ON");  }
  cclient.println("<br><br>");  
  cclient.println("Turn <a href=\"/LED=ON\">ON</a><br>");  
  cclient.println("Turn <a href=\"/LED=OFF\">OFF</a><br>");  
  cclient.println("</html>");
  Serial.println("");  
}

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {     mqttpayload += (char)payload[i]; }
}

void reconnect() { 
  if (!client.connected()) { 
    while (!client.connected()) { 
      Serial.print("MQTT..");  
      if (client.connect("2021", mqtt_user, mqtt_pass)) { 
        Serial.println("MQTT connected");        client.subscribe(mqtt_topic);   
      } else { error(); } 
    }  
  }  
  client.loop(); 
}

void error() {  Serial.print("failed, rc=");      Serial.print(client.state());      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");      delay(5000);   }
```

The problem lies when I test it while connected to my router with **no internet**. The code loops trying to connect to MQTT server and get stuck which doesn't allow me to send local HTTP requests.

I tried modifying the MQTT reconnect loop to the one below, which solves the problem but introduces another issue which is delaying the HTTP requests up to 6-9 seconds.

```js
void reconnect() { 
 if (client.connect("2021", mqtt_user, mqtt_pass)) { 
  Serial.println("MQTT connected");
  client.subscribe(mqtt_topic);   
 } else { error(); }
 client.loop(); 
}
```

So the question here, **what should I do to get around this issue?**

Comment: You should only try connecting to your MQTT server when there's no active connection. With your second piece of code you are (re)connecting every iteration of your `loop()` and this might introduce the delay you seem to be experiencing. Place an `if (!client.connected) { ... }` around the `if (client.connect()) { .. }` code.

Comment: @StarCat if you look at the main code, it's there, and this is what makes it troublesome to me. if internet connectivity is lost, this will hold Arduino from receiving my HTTP requests.

Comment: You could throttle the amount of reconnect attempts by only calling `reconnect()` every few seconds and not continuously. I've had good results with checking once every 30 seconds. If you do that, you should call `client.loop()` from your main `loop()` and not from `reconnect()`.

Comment: It's quite simple: on each iteration of loop() *if* the client isn't connected *then* try to connect. Not *while* the client isn't connected *then* try to connect. Only try once each time through.

Comment: You could look at the PubSubClient example `mqtt_reconnect_nonblocking` which might be what you're looking for. It only tries to connect when there's no connection (I assumed your code already did this, but it looks like it doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

In the loop, check the network first, you can also ping to internet to make sure the internet is available. If negative, just skip reconnecting and try to check the internet connection or [try another way to connect to MQTT or esp](https://www.programmingboss.com/2020/11/industrial-automation-based-on-node-red-and-raspberryPi.html).